How to recover the call after refresh page
I'm relatively new to SIP.js and WebRTC, and I've managed to implement SIP.js for making outbound and receiving inbound calls successfully. However, I'm facing an issue when it comes to recovering the call state after a webpage refresh. I am using SIP.JS 0.20, and Asterisk 18
I've attempted to retrieve the CallId, FromTag, and ToTag from the session and attach them to extraHeaders, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working as expected. I've looked into resources like this post, but I'm still struggling to find a solution.
How do I properly recover the call state in SIP.js after a webpage refresh? Any insights, code snippets, or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.
I save to localstorage the session info as below (when receive a call):
localStorage.setItem('callId', simpleUser.getSession._dialog.dialogState.callId);
localStorage.setItem('localTag', simpleUser.getSession._dialog.dialogState.localTag);
localStorage.setItem('remoteTag', simpleUser.getSession._dialog.dialogState.remoteTag);

And when refresh the page, I load the last call:
simpleUser
    .call(target, {
      inviteWithoutSdp: false,
      extraHeaders: [`callid: ${callId}`, `from-tag: ${fromTag}`, `to-tag: ${toTag}`]
    })

